# Given date as parameter retrieve month and year

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, I want the system to automatically get the fixed date (14th) regardless of any time I request.

**Question**:
So do I need to write a custom function for this matter or are there any built in function that I can use?

I've also provided some example as below:

A=Current Date(input)
B=System output

**Scenarios**
Case 1
A: 2017-03-30
B: 2017-03-14

Case 2
A: 2017-05-31
B: 2017-05-14

Case 3
A: 2017-06-03
B: 2017-05-14

**PHP**

```
$fulldate = date("Ymd");
$year = substr($fulldate,0,4);
$month = substr($fulldate,4,2);
$date = substr($fulldate,6,2);

if($date <= 14){
$month -= 1;
}

echo $year.$month.'14';
```

**MySQL**

```
select * from table where DATE_FORMAT(my_date,'%Y%m%d') = $year.$month.'14';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the "last 14th of a month" in SQL with

```sql
select concat_ws('-', year(now()), month(now()), 14) - interval (day(now()) <= 14) month
```

The "trick" ist this part:

```sql
- interval (day(now()) <= 14) month
```

which will substract one month only if the current day is <= 14

So you can use this query

```sql
select * 
from `table`
where my_date = concat_ws('-', year(now()), month(now()), 14) - interval (day(now()) <= 14) month
```

without doing anything in PHP.

Using PHP you can do it the following way:

```php
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('-14 day');
$last14th = $date->format('Y-m-14');

echo $last14th;

$sql = "select * from `table` where my_date = '{$last14th}'";
```

**Update**

Looking at the PHP code I realized, that the same logic can be used in SQL:

```sql
select date_format(now() - interval 14 day, '%Y-%m-14')
```

Comment: if the current date is not less than 14 then it will return incorrect result right?

Comment: @4LeaveCover It will return the 14th of this month, which I thought is your intention. If you run the first query now, it will return '2017-02-14'.

Comment: Can you break down the where clause with explanation? pleasee. Whats the function of the month behind?

Comment: @4LeaveCover Sorry, how should i break down something as simple as `where my_date = '2017-02-14'`? Consider - you didn't tell what you want to achieve with the query. I just copied and modified your query.

Comment: If your question is about the first query: `year(now())` = current year; `month(now())` = current month; `concat_ws(..)` will constract a date string in the format `Y-m-14`; `- interval X month` will substract `X` months from the constructed date; `X` is `0` or `1` depending on the condition `day(now()) <= 14` while `day(now())` is the current day of month.

Comment: Sorry I have hard time breaking down if lots of repetitive characters involved. Btw, nicely explained and here's my acceptance.

Answer (score -1):

you may use this:

```
select DAY(DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-03",'%Y-%m-%d'));
+-------------------------------------------+
| DAY(DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-03",'%Y-%m-%d')) |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                         3 |
```